# How to convert a varchar datetime to timestamp in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, view, type-conversion, presto

I'm having a problem converting this varchar into an AWS Athena datetime

"2012-06-10T11:33:25.202615+00:00"

I've tried some like date_parse(pickup, %Y-%m-%dT%T)

I want to make a view like this using the timestamp already converted

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_ton AS
(
SELECT
id,
date_parse(pickup, timestamp) as pickup,
date_parse(dropoff, timestamp) as dropoff,
FROM "table"."ton"
)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_datetime()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime) function:

```
presto> SELECT parse_datetime('2012-06-10T11:33:25.202615+00:00', 'YYYY-mm-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ');
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2012-01-10 11:33:25.202 UTC
(1 row)
```

(Verified on Presto 339)